# Illustrator pen tool edges are way too sharp

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

I'm trying to draw a vector diamond with a tutorial, but when I connect two anchor points the corner becomes extremely sharp. Why is that happening?

Here's an example of what's happening

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That happened because you connected the two vertical lines, giving an extreme **small angle**, resulting in a very pointy tip. You could change the corner appearance in the stroke palette (e.g. round) to adress this. But you really only need to connect them if you want to draw a shape.

Comment: In addition to KMSTR's answer: The mitre limit (in the stroke panel) can also alter the appearance of corners.

Answer (score 0):

In the transform --> stroke panel you can choose the type of corner you want to have, on CS6 anyway :-)